# Finder forgets /Applications folder's view options on each log in

Tags: finder, permission, folders

I recently did a fresh install of macOS 10.13.5 on my MBP, and came across a problem with my `/Applications` folder that I haven't been able to solve.

Finder will forget that folder's view options and the position and size of the window in each log in. It only happens with the `/Applications` folder, as far as I can tell.

What I have tried and didn't work:

- Repair permissions on entire boot disk.
- Manually set permissions of `/Applications` to read and write for everyone.
- Delete `/Applications/.DS_Store` to let Finder create a new one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you, select the Applications folder, right click on it, and then select "Show View Options"

Comment: Don't randomly change the permissions on system folders.